# How to create a color grading LUT for Unity URP?

Tags: unity, color, post-processing

I'm watching a movie, and I would like to achieve the same colors in my game.

[image: Movie color example]

I think I have to use a Color Grading lookup table to achieve this in Unity with URP.

[The best example I found example deals with Photoshop](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=TQkI5XZ7pfE), but it didn't include any information or description, it was just a raw screen capture which I didn't really understand.

How can I create a LUT?

Comment: Presumably you started by [searching for colour grading tutorials](https://www.google.com/search?q=urp+color+grading+tutorial)? What have you tried so far based on your research into this topic?

Comment: @DMGregory I quickly tried the URP PP options like Color Adjustments and ToneMapping, and I didn't find anything that would allow me to turn down the red channel. And I did read that URP PP is still very much in the making, so I wondered how I could achieve the effect, and I wondered if this is perhaps just not possible with URP PP yet.

Comment: [URP supports using a colour correction lookup table as described in this thread](https://forum.unity.com/threads/how-configure-color-lookup-urp.819780/).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

LUTs can be used in Unity URP by

1. Creating a Volume in the Inspector ("Create" -> "Volume" -> "Global Volume")

[image]

2. Clicking "New" to create a new Volume Profile:

[image]

3. Clicking "Add Override" in the newly created Volume, then "Color Lookup".

[image]

4. Checking "Lookup Texture" and then assing a LUT in the slot next to it.

[image]

For the LUT, I have used one of the free samples that come with the free "Amplify Color" asset in the Unity Asset store.

The results are visible right away in both the scene view window and in the gameview window.

Also make sure that "Post Processing" is activated in the camera.
I think by default it is not activated.

[image]